# How to make toolbar rounded and arc toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I was wondering how can I make toolbar like this

[image]

as you can see, there is an arc on the toolbar and it's archor the views to it , I tried to use an image for this , but it doesn't right I think and the result was bad

could you help me to do so ?

Comment: This library should help: https://github.com/developer-shivam/Crescento Also, it's better to use `AppBarLayout` in order to anchoring those Fabs and etc.

Answer (score 1):

For the `toolbar` `background` use following `drawable` ,

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="8dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#3083af"
        android:pathData="M24 24v-24h-24v24a20 36 0 0 1 24 0z"/>

</vector>
```